# Swift - Hide view if touch outside of it

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, touch, uigesturerecognizer

I'm currently coding a calendar system on my app. 
I already show / hide the calendar with a UIButton, with `toogleCalendar()` function that I created.

> I would like to hide the Calendar when the calendar is displayed and
>   if the user touch outside of it.

Something like that:

[image]

If I click outside of the calendar, the calendar disappear.

I tried to insert a subview and add a GestureRecognizer on it but it's not working.

Do you have any idea about how I could do that?

This is the toggle function:

```
func toggleCalendar(){
      if !calendarIsHidden {
         calendarIsHidden = true

         UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            self.shadowCalendarView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.95, y: 0.95)
            self.shadowCalendarView.alpha = 0
         }) { (finish) in
            if finish {
               self.shadowCalendarView.isHidden = self.calendarIsHidden
            }
         }

      } else {

         calendarIsHidden = false
         self.shadowCalendarView.isHidden = self.calendarIsHidden

         UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            self.shadowCalendarView.transform = .identity


            self.shadowCalendarView.alpha = 1

         }) { (finish) in
            // Nothing for now
         }

      }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code? what happened? (what's the part you faced an issue?)

Comment: Add a button on shadowCalendarView and in action hide the calendar. Flow should be shadowCalendarView inside Btn, Calendar. If you add tap gesture it works on calendar also so, it wont be proper user interaction to calendar

Comment: Add a tap gesture to self.view.

Comment: How are you achieving the dim effect on the view below the calendar? Add a tap gesture to that view.

Answer (score 3):

Add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your `self.view` and inside the `action` part of the constructor of `UITapGestureRecognizer` you will input a function in which you will present the logic for checking if your **calendar** is presented/enabled and can further hide it .

```
let mytapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(mytapGestureRecognizer)
self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

func handleTap(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){

  if !calendarIsHidden {
   calendarIsHidden = true

   //Hide the calendar here

  }
  else {
   calendarIsHidden = false

   // Show the Calendar Here
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You see how the screen blurs to darker color when the child view is open? You can add a black view with 0.5 (for example) alpha below your calendar and add a `UIGestureTapRecognizer` to it like so (I assume that is what `shadowCalendarView` is for?) :

```
// Somewhere in the code, for example on viewDidLoad if its a UIViewController, or anywhere in your dismissal function:
shadowCalendarView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(yourClassName.handleDismiss)))

@objc func handleDismiss() {
    // Dismisses the calendar with fade animation
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.calendarView.alpha = 0.0
        self.shadowCalendarView.alpha = 0.0
    }) { ( finished ) in
        self.calendarView.isHidden = true
        self.shadowCalendarView.isHidden = true
        // If you are implementing calendar as a child view, remove it in the completion block of the animation like so:
        self.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        self.view.removeFromSuperview()
        self.removeFromParentViewController()
    }
}
```

If this answer is not clear enough, try to provide more information and I will try to edit accordingly. For example the implementation, is it a new ViewController as a childView? Is it a View only?

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 5.1**

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
    {
        let touch = touches.first
        if touch?.view != self.yourView { 

          // Do whatever you wanna do
          yourView.isHidden = true
        }
    }
```